# improving Eclipse swt performance

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, swt

What ways are there to speed up creating SWT Composites, i.e. the time it takes for:

```
new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE)
```

to complete?

I have several composites that are shown editors in my RCP application. After tuning the database queries for their contents I found out that creating the composite itself is now the main bottleneck. For example, our most important composite takes 350ms to be created (on Windows 7). It contains absolutely no logic, all of the code is generated by SWT designer. (EDIT: so this time is spent entirely in creating the UI components; this question has nothing to do with data access)

Do you think this is a reasonable amount of time or is this a long time?

My most important composite has four sections, four table viewers each of which has at most 6 columns, two of which are hidden inside a CTabFolder, 6 text areas/fields, 5 buttons, two ComboViewers and two toolbars with in total 12 toolitems. The only layout I use is gridlayout.

I use a FormToolKit to create my components. When I do not use it and when I do not use images, the call to the Composite constructor still takes over 300ms.

EDIT: 
today with less applications open, creating the composite runs in 200ms

creating 700 Text controls in a Shell with either gridlayout or filllayout takes 640ms
The exact count of all controls in my composite (counted recursively using Composite.getChildren()):

```
Composite -> 9
Text -> 6
Button -> 5
Label -> 5
Table -> 4
Section -> 4
Combo -> 2
ToolBar -> 2 (containing 13 toolitems)
TabFolder -> 1
```

EDIT 2: I ran JVisualVM profiler and found that calls to Section.setExpanded(true) which I added with SWT designer by simply setting expanded property to true take a lot of time. These calls were unnecessary because they were already expanded! This reduced time with 25% to 150ms. Next biggest thing is creating the table viewers which takes 15% of the time, then setting column widths taking another 8% of the time. Almost all of this time is spent with native calls to Windows. After this, most time is spent creating sections, composites, comboviewers etc... So I guess there is not much I can do to further improve the performance.

Comment: 350ms is an eternity, it shouldn't take that long. How are your TableViewers populated? They are connected to a data model, and that can cause the delay.

Comment: I would like to know how you are loading data from Database. you should be using Eclipse jobs/ thread pool to load and not to block UI Thread. SWT UI event handling happens on UI thread ( single threaded model)

Comment: On my system (GTK) I need to create 700 components (Text input fields) to spend 300ms. How many components do you have on your composite?

Comment: - I am using org.eclipse.swt_3.7.0.v3735b.jar (bundled with Eclipse RCP 3.7)

Comment: - The time I mention is spent in creating SWT controls only, it does not include loading data from the database neither does it
 include populating the controls. So no table viewer input is set at all. (I completely separated this from the UI using data binding).
 - Now that I think about it, my java user.home is set to a network share and I remember that when I was not connect SWT complained. I will verify this now.

Comment: The time mentioned does not include database access neither populating the composite with data. I agree using a background thread to not block the UI thread is generally a good idea. This is still a low priority todo because the data access time is not problematic at the moment.

Comment: (that last point is not the problem, it's only that SWT seems to put the native libraries in the user home directory but it did not affect performance when I changed user.home variable to local disk)

Comment: Did you find out any way to increase the performance? I have the same issue with creating lot of composites

Comment: @appcoder I have had some performance issues caused by calling layout on a Composite before all of it's contents are created. The unnecessary calls to Section.setExpanded(true) before the contents if the section are created is an example of this. I have also seen issues with tables with very many items that I solved by using SWT.VIRTUAL style, which speeds it up significantly even though my TableViewer has static content. But your issue may be anywhere, so you could use a profiler like JVisualVM to get a better understanding of performance bottlenecks.